# Dynamically load Javascript code inside a new <script> tag

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've seen many answers in SO suggesting to change the `src` attribute for the `<script>` tag or using `.load()` JQuery function, when using an Ajax call to load a new Javascript file. But I want to execute the code directly added to a new `<script>` tag:

```
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.innerHTML = myCodeVariable;
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

How can I force this code to be loaded dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean with *dynamically*? This is *dynamically*. It doesn't get more *dynamic* than that. Do you have an error?

Comment: What `myCodeVariable` contains?

Comment: Why not just use `eval` to execute the javascript?

Comment: @ArtjomB. - *Dynamically* because it is called doing an Ajax call, and the code is not executed, but sent to the client. There are no errors

Comment: @DhavalMarthak - `myCodeVariable` contains a valid Javascript code (any).

Comment: This should work. Check if the js in `myCodeVariable` valid and if the snippet you presented is ever even called.

Comment: @ColinE - I've tried `eval(script)` at the end of the previous code without success. The code is not executed.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - As I've said the code is valid and sent to the client, but not executed.

Comment: If you check this link http://jsfiddle.net/C6WbL/1/, you will see that the code is executing correctly. Maybe there is an error in the code in the `myCodeVariable` and the execution stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working well, probably the wrong code is in "myCodeVariable" variable.
Can you post the value of this variable?

I created a simple code that show that your code is working;

HTML

```
<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5" id="textScript">alert("Hi, it´s a test");</textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="InsertScript();" value="execute" >
```

JS

```
function InsertScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.innerHTML = document.getElementById("textScript").value;
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

It is runing in http://jsfiddle.net/2KdRP/

Comment: You're right. My code was executed, but the events of this code were not sent due to other issue.